# Services do not start after on Debian Squeeze but do on Debian Lenny

Tags: service, debian, runlevel

the title pretty sums up everything.
I've got services that smoothly start on Debian Lenny, including after reboot.
This is not the case on Squeeze. Services can be manually started and run fine, but after reboot, it seems they're not triggered at all.

Any idea how to investigate the matter a bit further?

Thanks in advance,

Rolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. The issue is not in runlevel setting (use sysv-rc-conf package to configure runlevels) and not in /etc/default/ setting.

UPDATE: I solved the issue. The entire problem was in the way I configured the runlevels. I used the `sysv-rc-conf` to manually change the runlevels, but the application needed other settings as well.
When I used

```
insserv /etc/init.d/<file>
```

it loaded the preset configuration and the after the reboot it finally worked and was started properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable a init script with:

```
update-rc.d <yourscript> defaults
```

The script will start in runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5, but if the package is in Debian's repositories, it is likely to be
already configured the right way.

Depending on the package, there can be a variable in /etc/default/
to set to start the daemon at boot.